# 2 responses from ajax call to php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the code below i need 2 values from the response

1. Html response of the called page url
2. The value of the URL which was used to get the page **OR** the array index which was used in the call.

   ```
     for (i = 0; i < pageURLs.length; i++) {  
       $.ajax({

       url:  pageURLs[i],
       dataType: 'html',
       statusCode: {
           200: function(response) {
             /*i am only getting access to the html of the page HERE*/



           },
           404: function() {
                 /*404 here*/

           }
       },
       error: function(error) {

       }
   });}
   ```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**  Here is a more lightweight way of doing this, using `let`. See original response for explanation.

**Notice** This syntax might not be compatible with old browsers... :(

```
for (i = 0; i < pageURLs.length; i++) {
    let j = i;  
    $.ajax({
        url:  pageURLs[j],
        dataType: 'html',
        statusCode: {
            200: function(response) {
               /* now you can also access j */
               console.log("j=", j);
            },
            404: function() {
              /*404 here*/
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
            // error processing
        }
    });
}
```

---

**Original answer**

You need to wrap your loop body in a function, because the function scope will be preserved within the callback. Thus, you will be able to retrieve the correct `i` value within your callback.

```
for (i = 0; i < pageURLs.length; i++) {  
    (function(i) {
        $.ajax({
        url:  pageURLs[i],
        dataType: 'html',
        statusCode: {
            200: function(response) {
             /*i am only getting access to the html of the page HERE*/ 
             /* now you can also access i */
            },
            404: function() {
              /*404 here*/

            }
        },
        error: function(error) {

        }});
    }(i);
```

}